# How to add rel=sponsored to affiliate links in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Instead of doing it manually in for each link in my Wordpress
example: Foobar

I would like some solution in separate php file in my child theme. All my affiliate links are cloaked and I have specific folder on my domain where from I redirect them 
example: http://example.com/Go/affiliatelink

Is there any php solution for this?